# Как получить адрес сайта по кнопке на сайте?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь написать парсер, на сайте есть кнопка, которая получает gps координаты и открывает гугл карты по этим координатам. Я бы хотел получить координаты или ссылку, но не понимаю как это сделать. Для парсинга использую BeautifulSoup
Помогите написать код.

Код кнопки:

```
<a data-ng-click="vm.getDirections(vm.locationData.location.id)" target="_blank" class="btn ftl btn-info btn-xs" style="z-index: 100; vertical-align: top; margin-top: 2px;">Get Directions</a>
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup не умеет нажимать на кнопки, это не его профиль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается данная задача, с помощью библиотеки Selenium

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
            driver.get(self.link)
            #Указываем текст кнопки, у меня "Get Directions"
            element = driver.find_element("link text", "Get Directions")
            element.click()
            #Получаем список всех вкладок и выбираем новую
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            link_to_map = driver.current_url
```